# Task switch time from Rhealstone benchmark with pthread_yield()

Tags: pthreads, real-time, benchmarking

I'm trying to implement the task switch Rhealstone benchmark in Linux. Here is the original code: 
http://pastebin.com/aYF4Tnvt

And here is what I've written so far:
http://pastebin.com/tX7zK7h7

The problem is that the for loops run for a random few times and the program quits. Anyone can point me to the right direction? I'm a noob programmer and I'm really lost with this stuff.

Comment: You should be using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` rather than `CLOCK_REALTIME`.

Comment: Why is that? What difference does it make?

Comment: `CLOCK_REALTIME` is time-of-day time, which means that it can jump forwards or backwards as the clock is adjusted (eg by NTP).  `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` advances at the rate of wall-clock time, but never jumps forwards or backwards - it's for measuring time intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

join() the threads in main().  You are falling out of main and exiting your program which kills the other threads.  Change the code to something like

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start_time);

pthread_t threadID[2];

pthread_create(&threadID[0], NULL, task1, NULL);

pthread_create(&threadID[1], NULL, task2, NULL);  

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    pthread_join(threadID[i], NULL);

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end_time);

//... the rest
```

Not sure exactly where you want to put that end timer.  In this manner you would also be timing the two calls to join() but they should be minimal.  If you put the timer before the join then you will be ending your timer way before your threads actually end - all you will be timing is how long it takes to for two create_thread calls to complete.